# Running Bower from Jenkins git configuration

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, bower

I'am trying to run a `bower install` through Jenkins and I'm getting the following errors:

```
[INFO] bower bootstrap-popover-extra-placements#*  not-cached git://github.com/tarlepp/bootstrap-popover-extra-placements.git#*
[INFO] bower bootstrap-popover-extra-placements#*     resolve git://github.com/tarlepp/bootstrap-popover-extra-placements.git#*
[INFO] bower moment#~2.10.2                        not-cached git://github.com/moment/moment.git#~2.10.2
[INFO] bower moment#~2.10.2                           resolve git://github.com/moment/moment.git#~2.10.2
[ERROR] bower angular-route#~1.3.15                    ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection timed out
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Additional error details:
[ERROR] fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
[ERROR] github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection timed out
```

I have configured `git` to use `http://` instead of `git://` using `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` and bower install works normally from the command line (and uses the `http://` protocol) but not from `Jenkins` where it insists on using `git://`.

I also have opened port `9418/tcp` on the firewall -

```
public (default, active)
  interfaces: ens32
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 9418/tcp 9000/tcp 8080/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Still Jenkins insists on using git:// which times out. Any solutions?

Comment: Hi Were you able to solve this? I am currently facing this same issue with Jenkins and Bower...

Comment: Yes, I added a .gitconfigure file with url."https://".insteadOf git:// in the Jenkins root folder and it worked :)